JanusGraph traversal returns Vertex instead of JanusGraphVertex
I'm using Java to connect to JanusGraph 1.0. I'm having trouble understanding why JanusGraph would ever return a Vertex.
JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('configfile');
JanusGraphVertex jgv = graph.addVertex('city');
Vertex gv = graph.traversal().V().hasLabel('city').next();

I'm wondering if I'm missing something that will lead to mixing things up or really suboptimal solutions. Is the intent for the JanusGraph library to be for writing with transactions while reading uses the Gremlin classes?
Editing to try and clarify:
JanusGraph object has a traversal method it inherits from Graph with no modifications. AFAIK there isn’t another way to traverse a graph using the JanusGraph library classes. For example, I don’t see a way to run g.V().next() and get a JanusGraphVertex. Am I overlooking something? Is there another way to traverse the graph? Or are you supposed to just work with two different Vertex classes?
I think my question might boil down to why isn’t there a JanusGraphTraversal class?

not sure if I do understand the question... traversal() is a method of TinkerPop, which is intended to work with different databases, not only JanusGaprh. So it methods/classes/... are designed so that the returned types are from TinekrPop and not database specific. Vertex is an interface which probably JanusGraphVertex is implementing... try printing the result of gv.getClass() to see which class that instance is from

Right, so JanusGraph has a traversal method it inherits from Graph with no modifications. AFAIK there isn’t another way to traverse a graph using JanusGraph classes. For example, I don’t see a way to run g.V().next() and get a JanusGraphVertex. Hopefully that makes more sense?

not exactly right, I don't know that libraries, but I believe that Graph is an interface (no implementation of methods) and JanusGraph is implementing that interface, that is, it is indeed implementing the traversal() method. I do not have JanusGrap, neither its documentation, nor will I install it... I wrote "try printing..." in my previous comment, did you? :-|

( eventually you can cast the Vertex, not sure why you need it, not saying it is the correct to do... if (gv instanceof JanusGraphVertex) { JanusGraphVertex jgv = (JanusGraphVertex) gv; ... } )

actually JanusGraph itself is an interface, so it is not implementing the method either... it is implemented by the instance (of StandardJanusGraph) returned by the Factory (always assuming it is not a default method)

Re printing, it’s a good idea. I’ll try it when I’m fully out of bed :-)

You are correct. They both return org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.StandardVertex. If you do a quick answer I'll accept it.
